# Вычисление корня методом бисекции

Tags: python

Не выдает корень из функции. Вычислял методом бисекции (дихотомии) на python

```
#const
#точность корня (10е-20)

eps=float(input(print('e')))  

Kw=10**(-14)
Ka=1.75*10**(-5)

#границы а и b на оси абсцисс

a=float(input(print('a')))  
b=float(input(print('b')))

c0=float(input(print('конц-ция')))


f=lambda x: (10**(-2*x)-Kw)/Ka + 10**(-x) + Kw/(10**(-x)) - c0  
 
while abs(f(a)-f(b))>eps:
      q=(a+b)/2
      if f(a)*f(q)<0:
            b=q
      else:
            a=q

print(q)
```

данные, которые ввожу. далее ничего не выдает:

[image: данные, которые ввожу. далее ничего не выдает]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: А как следовало бы тогда? Если через функцию, параметрами которой будут границы а и b?

Comment: Просто уберите все `print` из всех `input`: `eps=float(input('e'))`

Comment: `10е-20` - это недостижимая точность на встроенном типе `float`, для такой точности нужно что-то помощнее использовать.

Comment: просто там есть константа с порядком равным -14 (Kw). поэтому взял такую точность

Answer (score 2):

1. Под "точностью вычисления корня" обычно понимают `abs(a-b)>eps`, а не `abs(f(a)-f(b))>eps`, поскольку корень - это именно значение x, в котором целевая функция достигает нуля, а не значение функции.
2. Из-за конечной точности операций с плавающей точкой цикл:

```
while a!=b:
      a=(a+b)/2
```

может отказаться как конечным, так и бесконечным.
Т.е.  `a!=b`, но `(a+b)/2==a`, из-за потери последнего бита мантиссы в операции сложения.

Поэтому, рекомендую модифицировать цикл:

```
while abs(f(a)-f(b))>eps:
      q=(a+b)/2
      if (q==a) or (q==b):
            break # мы не достигли намеченной точности, но точнее посчитать невозможно
      if f(a)*f(q)<0:
            b=q
      else:
            a=q
```

см. например,: https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/operatsii-chislami-python/problemy-chisel-plavajuschej-zapjatoj/  , https://habr.com/ru/companies/skillfactory/articles/658277/

3. Ввод чисел обычно делается так:

```
eps=float(input('e'))
```

, тогда не  будет лишних None в выводе программы.

4. Выдаче программы, лучше приводить текстом а не картинкой. (Из окна консоли тоже можно копировать!)

Comment: спасибо большое